# How do you completely uninstall AMD Catalyst 13.11 Beta 9.5 Driver in order to revert to a previous version?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card

I have recently installed the AMD Catalyst 13.11 (Beta 9.5) Driver which has effectively nuked my system from a computational overlord to a substandard turd-brick. Thus, I have set out on a valiant quest to vanquish the evil beta driver from my computer in order to replace it with the currently "stable" 13.9 driver. See how I put stable in quotations? That's because I have no faith in AMD's drivers anymore.

Anyways, I have been unsuccessful in removing this filth from my computer. Here is what I have tried:

- Uninstalling all Advanced Micro Devices applications showing up under my Control Panel.
- Following all the steps in [guides on how to completely uninstall AMD graphics drivers.](http://www.brightsideofnews.com/news/2012/4/4/guide-how-to-completely-uninstall-amd-graphics-drivers.aspx)
- The AMD driver cleanup utility. I wish I still had a link to this, but this cleanup utility was even more filthy than the current beta driver, causing issues with UAC and other such problems all because it [removed a simple registry key that most system services seem to need](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/failed-to-read-description-error-code-2). Easy fix, but nonetheless filthy.
- Using [Driver Fusion](http://treexy.com/products/driver-fusion) to try and remove the filth.

The question remains, as to how I can remove this garbage, and send it back to the lowest circles of hell from which it usurped. :) The essential problem I am having is that, whenever I go through all these steps simultaneously, and it "appears" as if the driver is gone from my computer, the installation for the stable 13.9 driver craps out on me with errors, leading me to think that the old drivers are still installed on my system. That's not the only reason for me believing the drivers are still on my box, because even though I go through all these steps, when I reboot in a seemingly "clean" driver-less environment, my two monitors still start Windows under 1080p resolutions, which, I think is a little strange if I was to consider that the driver for my display adapter was removed from my computer...in my experience, when you truly remove drivers, your resolution goes down to a basic one.

A little information about my system:

- Alienware Aurora R4.
- Two Radeon HD 7950's (with CrossfireX).

Update: Here is the error log. Every time I try to install, the AMD Driver seems to be the point of failure as part of the Catalyst installer.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Report.xml.xsl"?>
<monetreport xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <general>
    <cmdline>-UI </cmdline>
    <time>12/11/13 19:57:55</time>
    <action>install</action>
    <download></download>
  </general>
  <dcm>
    <primary>
     <name>AMD Radeon Graphics Processor</name>
     <manufacture>Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.</manufacture>
     <chiptype></chiptype>
     <chipid>0x679a</chipid>
    <vendorid>0x1002</vendorid>
     <ssid>0x0b00</ssid>
     <ssvid>0x1002</ssvid>
     <classcode>0x030000</classcode>
     <revisionid>0x00</revisionid>
    </primary>
    <device>
     <name>AMD Radeon Graphics Processor</name>
     <manufacture>Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.</manufacture>
     <chiptype></chiptype>
     <chipid>0x679a</chipid>
     <vendorid>0x1002</vendorid>
     <ssid>0x7950</ssid>
     <ssvid>0x1545</ssvid>
     <classcode>0x030000</classcode>
     <revisionid>0x00</revisionid>
    </device>
    <device>
     <name></name>
     <manufacture>Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.</manufacture>
     <chiptype></chiptype>
     <chipid>0xaaa0</chipid>
     <vendorid>0x1002</vendorid>
     <ssid>0xaaa0</ssid>
     <ssvid>0x1545</ssvid>
     <classcode>0x040300</classcode>
     <revisionid>0x00</revisionid>
    </device>
    <device>
     <name></name>
     <manufacture>Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.</manufacture>
     <chiptype></chiptype>
     <chipid>0xaaa0</chipid>
     <vendorid>0x1002</vendorid>
     <ssid>0xaaa0</ssid>
     <ssvid>0x1002</ssvid>
     <classcode>0x040300</classcode>
     <revisionid>0x00</revisionid>
    </device>
  </dcm>
  <exist>
<package>
                <description>AMD Gaming Evolved App</description>
                <result></result>
                <version>1.10.000</version>
                <size>49 </size>
</package>
  </exist>
  <install>
<package>
                <description>AMD Catalyst Install Manager</description>
                <result>Succeed</result>
                <version>8.0.915.0</version>
                <size>20 </size>
</package>
<package>
                <description>Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x86)</description>
                <result>Succeed</result>
                <version>10.0.30319</version>
                <size>9 </size>
</package>
<package>
                <description>AMD Display Driver</description>
                <result>Fail</result>
                <version>13.152.1.8000</version>
                <size>90 </size>
</package>
<package>
                <description>Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x64)</description>
                <result>Succeed</result>
                <version>10.0.30319</version>
                <size>9 </size>
</package>
<package>
                <description>AMD Accelerated Video Transcoding</description>
                <result>Succeed</result>
                <version>13.15.100.31008</version>
                <size>3 </size>
</package>
<package>
                <description>AMD Catalyst Control Center</description>
                <result>Succeed</result>
                <version>2013.1008.932.15229</version>
                <size>150 </size>
</package>
  </install>
  <uninstall>
  </uninstall>
  <downloaded>
  </downloaded>
  <resource>
    <hwinfo>Hardware information</hwinfo>
    <existpkg>Existing packages</existpkg>
    <pkg2inst>Packages for install</pkg2inst>
    <pkg2uninst>Packages for uninstall</pkg2uninst>
    <otherdev>Other detected devices</otherdev>
    <errmsg>Error messages</errmsg>
    <name>Name</name>
    <manufacture>Manufacturer</manufacture>
    <chiptype>Chip type</chiptype>
    <chipid>Device ID</chipid>
    <otherhw>Other hardware</otherhw>
    <download>Download packages</download>
    <succeed>Success</succeed>
    <fail>Fail</fail>
    <vendorid>Vendor ID</vendorid>
    <classcode>Class Code</classcode>
    <revisionid>Revision ID</revisionid>
    <ssid>Subsystem ID</ssid>
    <ssvid>Subsystem vendor ID</ssvid>
    <header1>Catalyst™ Install Manager</header1>
    <header2>Installation Report</header2>
    <finalstatus>Final Status:</finalstatus>
    <versionofitem>Version of Item:</versionofitem>
    <size>Size:</size>
    <bytes>Mbytes</bytes>
  </resource>
  <error><msg>Driver Install: the installation failed</msg></error></monetreport>
```

Comment: Using `Device Manager` you should be able to tell Windows to delete the drivers.  At that point its only a matter of installing the version you want to use.  If you have tried this, then lets start with what errors your getting, because removing the driver should be enough.

Comment: @Ramhound I haven't thought of going down the Device Manager route. Thanks for the idea, I will try this tonight when I get home and if that doesn't work I will start posting back with errors from the installation.

Comment: Sometimes unplugging from pci-e and re-plugging or even switching to secondary bios can change the referencing of some unwanted files.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried it but it didn't work. I'll post the error code up top.

Comment: @Ramhound My bad. I tried uninstalling it from there but it must have reverted to a version of it...thinking about it I'll try to extract to local and get the correct driver for it loaded from the drivers folder.

Comment: @Ramhound Update for you...when I try to manually install it from the .inf in device manager i get the error, "Windows found software for your device but encountered an error while attempting to install it." -> "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: @Ramhound Any ideas?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik It might work, but I'm too damn lazy.

Comment: Since your lazy to try something I am to lazy to post a response

Comment: @Ramhound Success. The solution was all in the logs at C:\Windows\Inf\setupapi.dev.log...it had said it found the driver already inside a folder at 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\<PackageName>' when in fact that folder was not present so I manually created and copied the drivers to it, and it worked. BUT DON'T WORRY, YOU CAN KEEP ON BEING SENSITIVE, BUD :)